# Imagemagick yasm singularity build fails

Tags: docker, singularity-container, yasm

I am attempting to convert the docker file for :
https://hub.docker.com/r/dpokidov/imagemagick/
to singularity. The docker builds fine in docker. In my singularity def file the following line fails with the error.

yasm cmake 
libde265-0 libde265-dev libjpeg62-turbo libjpeg62-turbo-dev x265 libx265-dev libtool 
libpng16-16 libpng-dev libjpeg62-turbo libjpeg62-turbo-dev libwebp6 libwebp-dev libgomp1 libwebpmux3 libwebpdemux2 ghostscript

- yasm cmake
  yasm: warning: can open only one input file, only the last file will be processed
  yasm: file name already has no extension: output will be in `yasm.out'
  yasm: FATAL: Could not open input file
  FATAL:   failed to execute %post proc: exit status 1
  FATAL:   While performing build: while running engine: exit status 255

When I cut the list of names to 1 it still fails to open the file.
I can't find a reference for this with singularity.
The docker build looks the same and works fine. So I assume its a singularity thing?

Answer (score 1):

Seems like something with the assembler and the build environment being a bit different than it's expecting.

Is there a reason you're creating a definition file from scratch rather than using the docker image directly? `singularity pull docker://dpokidov/imagemagick` should give you what you need.

If you want to make further changes to the image, you can also use:

```
Bootstrap: docker
From: dpokidov/imagemagick

%post
# custom stuff here
```

Comment: Hi, Thanks for the reply. I translated the docker file to the definition file. I have not had an issue with singularity not running a docker file that builds. So this is a first. Any suggestions on where to look at the environment?

Comment: If you pasted the dockerfile contents into a singularity definition, the problem is the comment line above `yasm cmake`, and you will have problems with most of the other ones as well. Docker ignores comments in the Dockerfile, but they interrupt the line continuation when singularity executes it like a shell script